# How to working with data from client side using Observables

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the Grid of Kendo (Angular 2) for Add/Edit/Delete a Row in the grid:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/

In the original Code, the data is obtained from a rest service like this:

```
    private fetch(action: string = "", data?: Product): Observable<Product[]>  {
        return this.jsonp
        .get(`http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products/${action}?  callback=JSONP_CALLBACK${this.serializeModels(data)}`)
        .map(response => response.json());
     }
```

But, I want to work with a array for add/edit/delete rows in memory. Next, I want to do click in the button submit and send the data (with all my changes) to the server.

My solution for this is like this:

https://gist.github.com/joedayz/9e318a47d06a7a8c2170017eb133a87e

**Overview**:

I declare an array:

private view: Array = [{ProductID: 1, ProductName: "pelotas", Discontinued: undefined, UnitsInStock: 80}];

and override the fetch method like this:

```
  private fetch(action: string = "", data?: Product): Observable<Product[]>    {
/*return this.jsonp
  .get(`http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products/${action}?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK${this.serializeModels(data)}`)
  .map(response => response.json());*/

  debugger;

  if(action=="create"){
    var product : Product = new Product(-1, data.ProductName, data.Discontinued, data.UnitsInStock);
    this.view.push(product);
  }else if(action=="update"){
    var indice = this.view.indexOf(data);

    if(indice>=0)
    this.view[indice]  = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }else if(action=="destroy"){
    var indice = this.view.indexOf(data);

    if(indice>=0)
    this.view.splice(indice, 1);

  }


  return Observable.of(this.view);
 }
```

My Question is: Exists some way of communicate the create/update/delete of items in my array of a simple or reactive form to my grid?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using in-memory array you do not need to use Observables. The Grid component is already bound to the array, thus it is just necessary to manipulate the data. For example:

```
export class AppComponent {
    public dataItem: Product;

    @ViewChild(GridEditFormComponent) protected editFormComponent: GridEditFormComponent;

    private view: Array<Product> = [{ ProductID: 1, ProductName: "pelotas", Discontinued: undefined, UnitsInStock: 80 }];

    public onEdit(dataItem: any): void {
        this.dataItem = Object.assign({}, dataItem);
    }

    public onCancel(): void {
        this.dataItem = undefined;
    }

    public addProduct(): void {
        this.editFormComponent.addProduct();
    }

    public onSave(product: Product): void {
        if (product.ProductID === undefined) {
            this.createProduct(product);
        } else {
            this.saveProducts(product);
        }
    }

    public onDelete(e: Product): void {
        this.deleteProduct(e);
    }

    public saveProducts(data: Product): void {
        var index = this.view.findIndex(x => x.ProductID === data.ProductID);

        if (index !== -1) {
            this.view = [
                ...this.view.slice(0, index),
                data,
                ...this.view.slice(index + 1)
            ];
        }
    }

    public createProduct(data: Product): void {
        this.view = [...this.view, data];
    }

    public deleteProduct(data: Product): void {
        this.view = this.view.filter(x => x.ProductID !== data.ProductID);
    }
}
```